# Are Hack named functions fully first-class citizens?

Tags: hhvm, hacklang, first-class-functions

HHVM 3.9 is not such a fan of ternary statements with named functions, even when passed through `fun()`, but ≥3.10 is totally fine with them. It seems as though this is one of few cases, however, because 3.9 *does* accept named functions returned from concrete functions, as well as accepting named functions passed into other functions ([3v4l](https://3v4l.org/alChZ)):

```php
<?hh
echo ((() ==> fun('strlen'))())('Hello'); // 5
echo (($f, $v) ==> $f($v))(strlen, 'Hello'); // 5 + Notice: Use of undefined constant strlen - assumed 'strlen'
echo (true ? strlen : intval)('100'); // Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' on line 3
```

What changed between 3.9 and 3.10? Are there any cases in HHVM ≥3.10 where named functions cannot be referenced and used this way?

Answer (score 1):

First, when writing Hack, [don't write your code at toplevel; the `hh_client` typechecker can't check anything at toplevel](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/unsupported/top-level). And 3v4l doesn't run the typechecker at all, you need to run it locally.

That said, no, Hack doesn't really have first-class functions. Most of its behaviour here it inherited from PHP, which also doesn't have them. Back when I was working on the Hack team, we tossed around a lot of ideas for adding them to the language; it's an obvious addition and need. But the need was never *quite* strong enough such that we sat down and actually worked out the details for both the type system and runtime implications; in particular, how to work out some of the scoping issues that the current callables have. Anonymous functions fill out enough of the need, especially with [Hack's short lambda syntax](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/lambdas/introduction), that there was always something more pressing to deal with.

So Hack just has PHP's normal callable forms; [`fun` is one of a few special functions which give information to the typechecker that the string you specified actually represents a function](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/callables/special-functions) so the typechecker can do proper type analysis. But at the end of the day, `fun` just boils down to the usual PHP callable forms with a bit of extra magic in the typechecker.

As to the behaviour you indicate in your 3v4l link. Using `strlen` and `intval` like that would cause a type error in Hack, since those are syntactically constants but constants with those names don't exist since Hack doesn't have first-class functions -- or it would if the code weren't at toplevel and you were running the typechecker. As to why it causes a parse error in HHVM 3.9 (which masks the "invalid constant" errors you see in 3.10), I'm not 100% sure. Judging from [this example](https://3v4l.org/gXZVj) which works in PHP7 and HHVM 3.10, but not PHP5 and HHVM 3.9, my guess it is a [PHP7 feature that is backwards compatible and so is always enabled in HHVM](http://hhvm.com/blog/10859/php-7-support).

Comment: Ah, so this is more of a question of what _PHP7_ supports wrt named functions. I'm curious as to why the `Notice...undefined constant` is suppressed by `fun` if it "just boils down to the usual PHP callable forms", but it's a minor detail I suspect. To clarify: outside of type errors, there are no cases where `fun('foo')` and `foo` are interpreted differently, right?

Comment: The type errors are the entire point; they are emphatically not the same in the typechecker. However, [at runtime, yes](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/cc7f35361e5dfc934631e1e19e2f2b9f66890391/hphp/system/php/lang/fun.ns.php#L31-L67). EDIT: keep in mind the comments in the code I linked have code at toplevel and as such are wrong, but [the normal public docs](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/callables/special-functions) are right.